# bayesian pca using PyMC

Tags: python, pymc

I'm trying to implement Bayesian PCA using PyMC library for python. But, I'm stuck where I define lower dimensional coordinates...

Model is

*x = Wz + e*

where x is observation vector, W is the transformation matrix, and z is lower dimensional coordinate vector.

First I define a distribution for the transformation matrix W. Each column is drawn from a normal distribution (zero mean, and identity covariance for simplicity)

```
def W_logp(value):
   logLikes = np.array([multivariate_normal.logpdf(value[:,i], mean=np.zeros(dimX), cov=1) for i in range(0, dimZ)])
   return logLikes.sum()

def W_random():
   W = np.zeros([dimX, dimZ])
   for i in range(0, dimZ):
      W[:,i] = multivariate_normal.rvs(mean=np.zeros(dimX), cov=1)
   return W

w0 = np.random.randn(dimX, dimZ)

W = pymc.Stochastic(
   logp = W_logp,
   doc = 'Transformation',
   name = 'W',
   parents = {},
   random = W_random,
   trace = True,
   value = w0,
   dtype = float,
   rseed = 116.,
   observed = False,
   cache_depth = 2,
   plot = False,
   verbose = 0)
```

Then, I want to define distribution for *z* that is again a multivariate normal (zero mean, and identity covariance). However, I need to draw a *z* for each observation separately while *W* is common for all of them. So, I tried

```
z = pymc.MvNormal('z', np.zeros(dimZ), np.eye(dimZ), size=N)
```

However, *pymc.MvNormal* does not have a *size* parameter. So it raises an error. Next step would be

```
m = Data.mean(axis=0) + np.dot(W, z)
obs = pymc.MvNormal('Obs', m, C, value=Data, observed=True)
```

I did not give the specification for *C* above since it is irrelevant for now. Any ideas how to implement?

Thanks

## EDIT

After Chris Fonnesbeck's answer I changed my code as follows

```
numD, dimX = Data.shape
dimZ = 3
mm = Data.mean(axis=0)

tau = pymc.Gamma('tau', alpha=10, beta=2)
tauW = pymc.Gamma('tauW', alpha=20, beta=2, size=dimZ)

@pymc.deterministic(dtype=float)
def C(tau=tau):
    return (tau)*np.eye(dimX)

@pymc.deterministic(dtype=float)
def CW(tau=tauW):
    return np.diag(tau)

W = [pymc.MvNormal('W%i'%i, np.zeros(dimZ), CW) for i in range(dimX)]
z = [pymc.MvNormal('z%i'%i, np.zeros(dimZ), np.eye(dimZ)) for i in range(numD)]
mu = [pymc.Lambda('mu%i'%i, lambda W=W, z=z: mm + np.dot(np.array(W), np.array(z[i]))) for i in range(numD)]

obs = [pymc.MvNormal('Obs%i'%i, mu[i], C, value=Data[i,:], observed=True) for i in range(numD)]

model = pymc.Model([tau, tauW] + obs + W + z)
mcmc = pymc.MCMC(model)
```

But this time, it tries to allocate a huge amount of memory (more than 8GB) when running `pymc.MCMC(model)`, with `numD=45` and `dimX=504`. Even when I try it with only `numD=1` (so creating only 1 `z`, `mu`, and `obs`), it does the same. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, PyMC does not easily let you define vectors of multivariate stochastics. Hopefully we can make this happen in PyMC 3. For now, you would have to specify this using a container. For example:

```
z = [pymc.MvNormal('z_%i' % i, np.zeros(dimZ), np.eye(dimZ)) for i in range(N)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me add one more, are there any way to use __plates__ as in graphical models, in PyMC? Indeed, it would be very useful to have any example, first giving graphical model and then coding in PyMC.

Comment: Please see my EDIT in the question

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the memory issue, try using a different backend for the traces. The default (`"ram"`) keeps everything in RAM. You can try something like `"pickle"` or `"sqlite"` instead.

Regarding the plate notation, it might be something we could pursue for PyMC 3. Feel free to create an issue suggesting this in [our issue tracker](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues).